# Write data to text file in order

Tags: php, ajax, post

AM very new to PHP , I am just playing with PHP ,

Am getting data from form via ajax post to php , the data getting added to text file , I want to place that data in order

like

```
 1) username , emailid , etc  
 2) username , emailid , etc
```

now its getting added like this without any numbers

```
  username , emailid , etc  
  username , emailid , etc
```

below is my PHP code

```
<?php
    //print_r($_POST);
    $myFile = "feedback.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $comma_delmited_list = implode(",", $_POST) . "\n";
    fwrite($fh, $comma_delmited_list);
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: Your code is missing the number. What prevents you from adding it?

Comment: where ? how to add numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php

    //print_r($_POST);
    $myFile = "feedback.txt";

    $content  = file_get_contents($myFile);
    preg_match_all('/(?P<digit>\d*)\)\s/', $content, $matches);
    if(empty($matches['digit'])){
      $cnt  = 1;
    }
    else{
      $cnt  = end($matches['digit']) + 1;
    }

    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $comma_delmited_list = $cnt.") ".implode(",", $_POST) . "\n";
    fwrite($fh, $comma_delmited_list);
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: Please check `print_r($matches['digit']);` and see what is coming there

Comment: its just printing Array ( )

Comment: Ohhhhh I am so sorry, It is `preg_match_all('/(?P<digit>\d*)\)\s/', $content, $matches);` i wrote `$filename` instead of `$content`. I edited the code please check it now

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to add the new entry and sort all entries based on a "natural" order; i.e. the order a human would most likely put the elements in:

→ **Part 1**: Read .txt file in line-by-line

```
# variables:
    $myFile = "feedback.txt";
    $contents = array(); # array to hold sorted list

# 'a+' makes sure if the file does not exists, it is created:
    $fh = fopen( $myFile, 'a+' ) or die( "can't open file" ); 

# while not at the end of the file:
    while ( !feof( $fh ) ) { 

        $line = fgets( $fh ); # read in a line

        # if the line is not empty, add it to the $contents array:
        if( $line != "" ) { $contents[] = $line; } 

    } 
    fclose($fh); # close the file handle
```

→ **Part 2**: Add new entry and "naturally" sort list

```
# add new line to $contents array
    $contents[] = implode( ",", $_POST );

# orders strings alphanumerically in the way a human being would
    natsort( $contents );
```

→ **Part 3**: Write sorted lines to .txt file

```
# open txt file for writing:
    $fh = fopen( $myFile, 'w' ) or die( "can't open file" ); 

# traverse the $contents array:
    foreach( $contents as $content ) { 

         fwrite( $fh, $content . "\n" ); # write the next line 

    }
    fclose($fh); # close the file handle

# done! check the .txt file to see if it has been sorted/added to!
```

Let me know how that works.